# Block directive

Tags: magento2, template-directive

I'm wondering how I can include a .phtml file inside my cms block. I came across Magento directives which say to use the following:

```
{{block type="core/template" name="poop6" template="Magento_theme::test.phtml"}}
```

I imagine this would operate like my layouts xml where I do:

```
<block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" template="Magento_theme::test.phtml" />
```

I've found some very simple articles on the block directive, but none explicitly say where to store the file. I surmise that the "template" attribute works the same as the xml. In this case the test.phtml file is...

```
app/design/frontend/<theme_namespace>/<theme>/Magento_Theme/templates/test.phtml
```

Given that the xml `<block>` example above works, does anyone know why my block directive is not working? Is there more involved for this to work?

Sidenote, none of the articles I found say the Magento version, mine is 2.1.2. Also, the content where my directive is remains empty on the front end, so I believe Magento is at least attempting to interpret it and failing silently (nothing in debug logs).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer was to add the class attribute. No example I found online included this so hopefully this helps someone else out.

Here is basic example. When you copy the directive text into the content HTML editor like so, the `class` attribute is required. Here it is using the default:

```
{{block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" template="Magento_Theme::test.phtml"}}
```

Which will pull the html from

```
app/design/frontend/<theme_namespace>/<theme>/Magento_Theme/templates/test.phtml
```

This works on both cms page content and inside cms block content. It should also work in emails but I haven't tested that or anything else.

**Custom Module:**

With a custom module including a block seems slightly different:

```
{{block class="Namespace\ModuleName\Block\BlockName" template="Namespace_ModuleName::test.phtml"}}
```

Pulls the template from:

```
app/code/Namespace/ModuleName/view/frontend/templates/test.phtml
```

Comment: great job! Congrats on figuring out your own problem! This is good to know. Feel free to mark your answer as accepted.

Comment: Thanks! Another note, I believe Magento 1.x accepted the format I originally tried which is why I keep seeing it referenced everywhere.

Comment: In Magento 2 the "class" attribute has replaced the "type" attribute. Depending on your Magento version you only need one of them

Comment: @fschmengler good catch, I removed the type attribute from the answer after testing. Thanks!